# Java - fetch web contents skipping middle pages in response reaching to the desired response

Tags: java, web-crawler, web-content

Java
I have situation where i have to fetch web contents of response in result of form submit, but it is little tricky b/s the flow is not as simple as request and response, is as follows.

```
Submit button pressed -> Display page processing wait timer -> Display quick advertisement page -> Display page result.
```

Starting from "submit button pressed" i want to have "Display page result" contents and skip pages in between.

I have this sample code but it works only in one way, send request and receive response.

```
URL url;
InputStream is = null;
DataInputStream dis;
String line;

try {
    url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
    dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
     mue.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
     ioe.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // nothing to see here
    }
}
```

any java library can do it for me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to give a try to [Selenium web driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted). May be it has what you are trying to implement.

Comment: check if this post on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928813/how-can-i-ask-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-some-time) can help

Comment: Page i am requesting it loads form using ajax on page onload, thats why using HtmlUnitDriver it does not found form elements ? any suggestion

Comment: i eabled the javascript to load ajax components but it is giving restrict url exception on facebook contents.